# .location and getBoundingClientRect() function both return the x,y coordinates relative to the top right

Tags: javascript, selenium-chromedriver

Using *Selenium* chrome driver to locate coordinates of log in button on *Facebook.com*. All other field locations are given relative to top left corner.

I have tried:

```
driver.execute_script('var rect = arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect(); return rect;', log_button))

log_button.location
```

Comment: Is there an actual question in here somewhere? [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) states "Properties other than width and height are relative to the top-left of the viewport."

Comment: yes my question is why for one specific button am I getting the properties relative to the top-right corner

Comment: Can you share a [MCVR](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example that reproduces your issue or perhaps a larger chunk of your source code?